# How to delete 1 month old and older files in s3 using aws-cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

My bucket has already a lot of files and I want to delete files which are 1 month old and older.
I would like o delete files with out setting a Object Expiration.

Is there any way to do this using aws-cli? Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found [a blog post](http://shout.setfive.com/2011/12/05/deleting-files-older-than-specified-time-with-s3cmd-and-bash/) that contains a script that should take care of your needs.

More versatile version can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/JProffitt71/9044744) or written down below.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: ./s3cmdclearfiles "bucketname" "30d"
 
s3cmd ls s3://$1 | grep " DIR " -v | while read -r line;
  do
    createDate=`echo $line|awk {'print $1" "$2'}`
    createDate=`date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "$createDate" +%s`
    olderThan=`date -j -v-$2 +%s`
    if [[ $createDate -lt $olderThan ]]
      then
        fileName=`echo $line|awk {'print $4'}`
        if [[ $fileName != "" ]]
          then
            printf 'Deleting "%s"\n' $fileName
            s3cmd del "$fileName"
        fi
    fi
  done;
```

Comment: Is there no way of deleting the files aside from editing the configuration or adding an expiration. Because I don't want the files to automatic delete itself at a given time, I want to delete old files when I need to.

Comment: Came across this on Google and the first link seems to be made for an older release of date for Linux, because the -d argument does not take '-30d' as input. The 2nd link appears to be for Mac OS date. According to the GNU coreutils infopage date input format should be '30 days ago'. Based on that I modified the 1st script slightly: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1967872

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the actual code. Right now it relies on a blog and a gist, who knows if they will still be available in 2 years.