# AWS delete files older than 30 days aws cli

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to create a job that validates the oldest files in a bucket, after deleting them. I'm new to aws cli. Can someone help me?

OBS: I'm creating in bash.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete 1 month old and older files in s3 using aws-cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901556/how-to-delete-1-month-old-and-older-files-in-s3-using-aws-cli)

Comment: Or just set an [S3 Lifecycle expiration rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-expire-general-considerations.html).

Comment: What do you mean by "validates the oldest files in a bucket, after deleting them"?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using an S3 Lifecycle expiration rule, but if you have to do this in bash, try this:

```
BUCKET=""
aws s3api list-objects --bucket "$BUCKET" --query \
     "Contents[?LastModified<=\`$(date -v-30d '+%Y-%m-%d')\`][].{object: Key}" \
  | jq -r '.[].object' \
  | xargs -I {} aws s3 rm s3://$BUCKET/{} --dryrun
```